# Creating a totals page for timesheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that we use as a Time sheet.
It's made up of approx 80 tabs (Names of employees)

We have a front page, simply called "Totals"
This adds up a fortnights worth of hours into several Columns

When we make changes, we have several scripts to help make life easier
(Delete old sheets, duplicate master sheet, rename duplicate sheets, protect ranges etc...)

One script that we don't have though is one to create the totals page faster.

Our totals page has the name of every employee in column A, 
We use these names in our scripts to rename tabs etc...

I would like a script to link the calculations on the Totals Page, to the sheet and cell of every individuals tab.
We do this by manually by entering =nameoftab!C47 in the cells of the totals page.

What i want to do is =Totals!A3 C47
**So the cell pulls the sheet name from the name list on the left hand side, and points to C47 in the appropriate tab.**

This would allow us to add new people to our time sheet by simply adding their name to column A and not the formulas for ordinary time/overtime/travel time/allowances etc...

Can this be done?
I have played with several formulas/scripts to make this easier but to no avail

(Please let me know if you need me to be more specific)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this simple formula:

```
=indirect("'nameoftab'!C47")
```

or in your case:

```
=indirect("'" & Totals!A3 & "'!C47")
```

where Totals!A3 is cell with sheet name.

Comment: Thanks very much, I was hoping it would be this simple! 
Appreciate your help